# Send encrypted string between Android and Web API .NET

Tags: android, http, security, asp.net-mvc-5

One of my client whants to send encrypted string between native Android app and Web API .NET (ASP.NET MVC) over HTTP.

This question is not well described in Google as I could check.

So what is the common Security Framework for both sides to archive this goal?

Thank you!

Comment: Just use HTTPS, everything except the host address is encrypted.

Comment: @zaph I knew it, bro! Could you put a little bit more args and put it like an answer pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to encrypt the data between a client and server just use [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). HTTPS encrypts everything except the host address, even the query string and server directory portion is encrypted.

Essentially one can do no better for security that use HTTPS combined with the simplicity for the sender receiver. [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) protection is also provided.

Finally free server certificates are available from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).